# How to Pause and Resume bxSlider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

On my web page bxSlider starts when the page loads.  I would like to pause it 
at certain times, such as when the user clicks "Contact Us".  Then I would like to resume playing bxSlider when the "Contact Us" form closes.

I wasn't sure how to programmatically pause and resume bxSlider.  So I specified "autoHover: true" in the code below and used the trigger() method to emulate a mouseover or mouseout event, causing bxSlider to pause or resume.  But I would prefer not to specify "autoHover: true", since the user might inadvertently hover over bxSlider and cause it to pause.

I would be grateful if someone can tell me how to pause and resume bxSlider.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
         $('.bxslider').bxSlider( {
          auto: true,
          mode: 'fade',
          autoHover: true,
          pause: 1000
         });
    });

    function pausebx() { 
       $('.bxslider').trigger('mouseover'); 
    }
    function resumebx() { 
       $('.bxslider').trigger('mouseout'); 
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button id="btnOpenContactForm" onclick="pausebx()">Open Contact Form</button><br>
<button id="btnCloseContactForm" onclick="resumebx()">Close Contact Form</button><br>
</div>

<div>
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/images/S-1.gif"></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/images/S-2.gif"></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/images/S-3.gif"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Public Methods](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4#public-methods) stopAuto and startAuto for this

```
var slider=$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      //your code here
});

// pause
$(document).on('click','#btnOpenContactForm',function(){         
     slider.stopAuto();
});

// play
$(document).on('click','#btnCloseContactForm',function(){         
     slider.startAuto();    
});
```

Comment: I have a question.  I noticed that the following line works:

```$(document).on('click','#btnOpenContactForm',function(){ slider.stopAuto(); });
```
but this one does not work:
```
$('#btnOpenContactForm').on('click',function(){ slider.stopAuto(); });
```
In other words, if the first selector is "document" it works.

Can you explain why this is?  Thank you.

Comment: Your script is in head area of the document, so when you assign events on click there is no object to assign to (document not fully loaded). In my code event assigned to the document. So when page loads it works. Also you can use $(document).ready() to make $('#btnOpenContactForm').on('click') work. Document ready starts only when DOM ready, so you can assign your events. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/